# How to extract a string between two characters?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a string "foo [string] bar" and want to extract "string" out of it, dismissing all content before and after.

My grep has not the -P option, so I tried with sed.

```
echo "foo [string] bar" | sed -n -e '/\[/,/\]/p'
```

What I get is the full string in the command line.

Comment: Maybe `sed -n -e '/.*\[\(.*\)].*/\1/p'` but it will work for 1 pair of brackets per line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** if you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following then.

```
echo "foo [string] bar"  | awk -F"[][]" '{print $2}'
```

***2nd solution:*** With `sed` try:

```
echo "foo [string] bar"  | sed 's/\([^[]*\)\[\([^]]*\)\(.*\)/\2/'
```

***3rd solution:***

```
echo "foo [string] bar"  | awk '{sub(/[^[]*/,"");sub(/\[/,"");sub(/\].*/,"")} 1'
```

***4th solution:*** Considering  that your variable will have only 1 set of `[` and `]` if  this is the case then following simplest one will help you.

```
echo "foo [string] bar"  | sed 's/.*\[//;s/\].*//'
```

***5th solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` here.

```
echo "foo [string] bar" | awk 'match($0,/\[[^]]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

using `grep`:

```
echo "foo [string] bar" | grep -oP '\[\K[^]]+' 
string
```

If your grep supports `PCRE` (`-P` flag) ,the you can use the regex to capture the contents between `[` and `]`.
Here is the breakdown of the command:

`-o` : This flag will tell grep to print ONLY the matching regex , not the whole matching line.
`-P`: This will enable `PCRE`
`\[\K[^]]+` : `\K` will allow matching on the left of it, but do not consider it as part of output. `[^]]+` means, keep going if anything is matched  apart from `]`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "foo [string] bar" | awk '{gsub(/\[|\]/,"");print $2}'
string
```